# SMAPI mod loader for android questions?

Tags: stardew-valley

heyy i tend to us the SMAPI mod loader for android alot, it works fine, but it seems as if Stardew Valley Expanded doesn't work. does anyone know why it dosnt, spacecore has errors and i dont know how to change them.

Comment: What version (number) of the game are you playing?

Answer (score 1):

Some complicated mods (like Stardew Valley Expanded) might not work correctly on Android.

- Double-check if you have all depending mods. Look [here](https://github.com/FlashShifter/StardewValleyExpanded/wiki/Install-guide#required-mods) for more info.
- Mods are primarily coded for PC, and may not work correctly on Android if they use special libraries or similar.
- It might be a bug regarding SMAPI or any of the mods, though this is unlikely.

Ask around on [the Official Stardew Valley Discord](https://discordapp.com/invite/StardewValley) and see if anyone else has the same problem, perhaps they might be able to help.